# R plotting uneven axis

Tags: r, plot, axis

So I have this simple line graph I created in R, and I was wondering how to change the y-axis from what it is in the picture, to:

```
1000000
100000
10000
1000
100
10
1
```

And the x-axis to also just span from 1 - 25 including every tick.

I tried:

```
plot(dataTable[0:25], axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=seq(0, 25, 1))
axis(2, at=c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000))
```

Where dataTable looks like the following:

```
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10      11 
621266 496647 436229 394595 353249 305882 253983 199455 147380 102872 67255 
12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19     20     21     22 
41934  24506  13778  7179   3646   1778   816    436    217    114    74 
23     24     25     
49     44     26
```

But I keep getting

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Any Help?

[image: R Output:]

Comment: Could you please provide the `dput()` of your data for easier access and manipulation?

Comment: The use of the `scan()` function makes the provided data fairly easy to read into a vector. You just need to edit out the lines of labels, and that can be done on the console. Don't even need to put into an editor. Admittedly getting newbies to offer `dput(vec)` would be ideal, but I've given up when it's not needed (after whinging about it for years.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read `?par` and `?axis`. Need to suppress x-axis construction and then slightly shrink the size of the axis labels so they fit into the available spaces between the ticks. And need to specify `log="y"`:

```
d2 <- scan()
621266 496647 436229 394595 353249 305882 253983 199455 147380 102872 67255 41934  24506  13778  7179   3646   1778   816    436    217    114    74 49     44     26
```

Edited to give the scaling requested, which I misunderstood originally)

```
 png()
plot(d2, type ="b", log="y",axes=FALSE, ylim=c(1,10^7))
axis(2, at=10^(0:6), labels=formatC(10^(0:6),format="f", digits=0),
     cex.axis=0.8,las=2 )
axis(1, at=1:25, cex.axis=.6)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: plot(d2, type="b", col="red", lwd=3, log="y", axes=FALSE, ylim=c(1,10^7), 
+ axis(2, at=10^(0:6), labels=formatC(10^(0:6), format="f", digits=0), cex.axis=0.8, las=2), axis(1, at=1:25, cex.axis=.6))

I keep getting this same error.


Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: Those axis(...) calls are on separate lines, not part of the `plot(.)` call as you currently have them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ggplot2 solution. Attempted to reproduce style of your plot. As far as I know, you can't do what you want in base plot without writing your own custom plotting function, or using specified log plot function in some package.

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(x = 1:25, y = c(621266,496647,436229,394595,353249,305882,253983,199455,147380,102872,67255,41934,24506,13778,7179,3646,1778,816,436,217,114,74,49,44,26))
b = c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)
options(scipen=999)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_line(col = "red", size = 1) +
    geom_point(col = "red", shape = 1, size = 4) +
    scale_y_log10(labels = b, breaks = b) + 
    xlab("Coverage Threshold") +
    ylab("# Covered STRs")+ 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot2 example]

Comment: You should study base graphics more carefully before suggesting you "can't do" such a plot. It's actually quite simple. The entire plotrix-package is full of fancy plotting methods using entirely base graphics.

Comment: Hence the statement, "you can't do what you want in base plot without...using specified log plot function in some package." plotrix is not part of base R. Until someone produces a base-R solution that both labels and scales Y-axis, my statement holds true.

Comment: My advice to look at package-plotrix was to offer examples of what could be done with base graphics. Changing the y-axis scale is not at all difficult in base graphics.